# How to design multiple repositories that access the same real-time data using EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, irepository

I am actually looking for some help on learning the ropes on designing multiple Repositories that will access the same database using EF. I have seen sample code where each repository has it's own private DBContext, but am having difficulty with this concept. I am not interested in a Generic Interface in this project.

I want multiple interfaces where one is `Identity` based (on authorization) and other job specific repositories such as Categories, Items, etc in a single application where the inherited interfaces are reusable, hence the multiple `DbContext` instances.

In SQL you have transactions where you may commit or rollback the transaction, so in EF would multiple repos access the same (real-time) data? Maybe a better question would be how should I design my DAL when I want a single application to inherit many job specific repositories.

What did [jgauffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70386/jgauffin) mean by, 
**" make sure that your repository is 100% complete abstraction"**

What is meant by this?

Here is a quick example of what I am trying to figure out. Is this practice reasonable?

```
public class OneRepo: IRepository, IDisposable
{

private DbContext context = new DbContext();

// Methods and whatnot... 

}
```

And then a second repository also requires the same db connection by OneRepo but has separate in-memory Unit of Work I think?

```
public class AnotherRepo: IRepository, IDisposable
{

private DbContext context = new DbContext();

// Methods and whatnot...     
}
```

I apologize if my question is not well-written. I am relatively new to actually posting and I am not sure if I am making myself clear. I have already decided that I am not fond of generic repos in general and would like to create repos based on authorization and/or user tasks using Role Interface pattern. Any help explaining would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by real-time data? And where do you think problem of using different DBContext is?

Comment: I didn't mean I thought there was a problem I was wondering if having multiple DBContext instances running at compile time for different controllers might compromise the integrity of the data, but then I realised that this may be stupid to even think this because changes get persisted to the database.

Comment: Isn't that is why we adopt Unit Of Work or is the Unit of Work to ensure that we are using resources effectively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You inject the data context into your repositories

```
public class FirstRepo
{ 
   DbContext _ctx;

   public FirstRepo( DbContext ctx )
   { 
       this._ctx = ctx;
   }
}

public class AnotherRepo
{ 
   DbContext _ctx;

   public AnotherRepo( DbContext ctx )
   { 
       this._ctx = ctx;
   }
}
```

This way you can pass the same context to all repositories under the same unit of work.

Comment: Thanks for the sample and the explanation. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Save changes would be called in the UnitOfWork class...correct ?

Comment: @Bill I was going to ask about UoW also. I am also wondering when is it best to use a Role/Header Interface injection approach or use a dependency injection approach like Ninject? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dependency injection helps and only helps, it is not necessary. Save changes should be called from the UoW.

Comment: Thanks WZ. I would upvote every one of your answers, but I haven't earned enough reps yet. :-(